# How to connect mean.js to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, angularjs, aws

I am trying see how I can upload images and file to aws S3 via the mean.js framework. I am not sure how  the backend is linked to S3. There are no resources online about this specific framework and how it can be integrated with s3. Anyone cares to explain how?

Answer (score 0):

MEAN.JS is a full-stack JavaScript solution that helps you build fast, robust and maintainble production web applications using MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js.
So, I suggest looking for the right node module (use npm) which can handle the S3 connection with your node.js app